# Why can very long pipe (%>%) statements cause "Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit"?

Tags: r, ubuntu, tidyverse, pipe, rocker

Before I start:
I'm aware that there are quite a few threads on this error *"out there"* but none of them seem to narrow the problem down to very long pipe statements specifically.

By chance I came across the observation that very long pipe (`%>%`) statements can trigger the
`"Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit"` error.

Also, some machines I have access to will trigger this earlier while others will trigger it later.

`Ubuntu 20.04` with `R 4.0.5` (`rocker/r-ver:4.0.5`) tiggers **later**
`Ubuntu 22.04` with `R 4.3.2` (`rocker/r-ver:4.3.2`) tiggers **earlier**

Both machines return `8192` for `ulimit -s`.

Since I don't want to paste hundreds of lines of redundant code here I will give an example that will need to be adapted for personal reproduction on your local machine. Repeating the piping into the `mutate()` statement about 1000 times should do the trick on most machines.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:10000)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(col1 = 1)

  # uncomment and copy paste below lines until about 1000 mutate() statements are used
  #mutate(col1 = 1) %>%
  #mutate(col1 = 1) %>%
  #mutate(col1 = 1) %>%
```

As a solution I now break down long pipes into smaller chunks so that's easy enough really. I'm still interested in some more background on the topic.

Why does this trigger that error and does anyone have general thoughts on the topic?

In practice such long pipe chains may be implemented when creating ADaM datasets with workflows leaning on packages from the [`admiral`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/admiral/index.html) family.

Comment: I don't understand what is unclear. You create an extremely large [stack of function calls](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Stacks) and then wonder why that causes issues?

Comment: Thanks for kindly sharing insights! In retrospect - of course - it makes perfect sense. However, I still wonder about the different triggering times between OS and R Versions. Also, the intention of the thread is to point at this possibility if someone runs into that scenario. I was inspecting someone elses code on a different machine than the machine it was developed on and then ran into this error. Thus it took quite some time until I had figured out what the problem was and non of the other questions on the topic directed me along the long piping avenue.

Comment: To add even deeper context: The code was part of a package and hence it was also not directly clear which part of the package was triggering the error and why. With the oversimplified example here its much more obvious of course.

Comment: The C stack usage limit is OS dependent. You can increase it (at least on a *nix system) at the OS level.

Comment: My impression was that `ulimit -s` shows me the actual setting. This, however, returns the same (`8192 `) for both. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer** in reference to [Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland)'s comment:
Because very long chained pipe statements can create large [stacks of function calls](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Stacks).

**Long answer**:
In standard R it is unlikely that someone would nest hundreds of function calls to create a certain output. This is because such a statement would be hard to both read and write. It is much more likely that intermediate results would be generated, stored in individual variables and further processed downstream by the next required functions in the workflow thereafer, hence effectively preventing very large stacks of functions calls and the error described here.

Conversely, (by design) it is easily possible to create very large stacks of readable function calls with the pipe `%>%` (every layer in the entire pipe increases the stack) which can ultimately lead to the reported error if pushed to the extreme.

Comment: A technical aspect of why this may happen "sooner than expected" with pipes is that `%>%` is itself a function

Comment: Presumably one improvement would be using base `|>` pipe which isn't itself a function?

Comment: @AndyBaxter: that should cut the number of calls in half or so.

Comment: It would actually be useful to add the other information from the comments (e.g. about stack limit being OS-dependent) to your answer ...

Comment: I have a small followup question on the OS stack limit up in the question comments. I'd like to clarify that before I make appropriate edits.